# Can I connect the ground wire for my dryer to a different hole in the chassis?

Tags: electrical, grounding, dryer

I am installing a new GE electric dryer (model GTD42EASJ2WW) and attempting to connect the 4-wire cord.  The last step is to connect the green ground wire with a supplied ground screw.  The hole that is annotated with a ground symbol is behind the hot wires and somewhat inaccessible.  See photo below (hole in question is pointed to by red arrow):

[image]

Rather than connect to the hole that is annotated with a ground symbol, I attached the ground wire via another, much more accessible screw hole (see above).  I am wondering whether this is safe. In other words, as long as the grounding wire makes secure contact with the metal back of the dryer, will the dryer be grounded?  Or is there potentially something specific about that one hole marked with the ground symbol that requires that I connect the green wire there?

**Edit**: Additional information.  Below is from the installation instructions (available online at https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/assembly/GTD42EASJ2WW).  Note the description of the bracket as "strain relief bracket", which is distinct from the "strain relief."  The instructions (step 7) say that the hole for the ground screw is "above the strain relief bracket", which is consistent with where I put the ground screw.  The diagram in the installation instructions also appears consistent with where I put the ground wire.  The only thing that's inconsistent is the location of the ground symbol.

[image]

**Second Edit:** Taking a closer look, there *is* another ground symbol hiding behind the terminal of the red wire, just above and to the left of the strain relief bracket.  This is more consistent with the diagram in the installation instructions than I had thought, which gives me further confidence that I've connected ground to the correct spot.  Thank you everyone!

Comment: I see a split to the left is that plate separate ?  I use the back plane of equipment all the time but if that plate is a separate one attached by the black screw I would want to move the red pull it off if you need to it’s just a disconnect or female spade connector put your ground on then slip the red back on.

Comment: Is the hole the right size?  Was it threaded for that screw?  Was the crankdown force excessively light or excessively heavy?

Comment: What size of screw did you use?

Comment: @Harper I don't believe that the hole was threaded.  The screw fit very tightly and I had the impression that it was digging its own thread (might it be a self-tapping ground screw?).  The screw had a notch a the bottom, kind of like this: https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Ground-Screws-Cutting-Point/Multiple/1032TC/product.aspx?zpid=0419489.

Comment: What thread pitch did that screw have? Was it a pitch similar to an ordinary sheet metal screw, or a fine pitch, similar to what you'd find on the screw you linked, or a more typical grounding screw for that matter?

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't worry me, provided it backs out and goes back in with ~normal torques. @ThreePhaseEel it's a green screw and I presume it's the one intended to go in the other hole, so surely -32???

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I don't know.  It's the grounding screw that came with the dryer.  Being a complete novice, I don't quite follow where you're going with the questions about the screw.  Can you clarify what you're trying to determine?

Comment: @diy8675309 -- it sounds like you're in good shape then (I asked because a regular sheet metal screw is the wrong thing for this job, it *needs* to be a fine pitch screw to meet UL and NEC requirements for grounding)

Comment: @Harper -- yeah, it'd be -32 if it's the screw that came with the dryer, which it seems to be

Comment: @diy8675309 -- btw, if you would post your second edit as an answer, I'll +1 you for it

Answer (score 1):

Taking a closer look, there is another ground symbol hiding behind the terminal of the red wire, just above and to the left of the strain relief bracket (see first photo in the question---the first horizontal line of the ground symbol is just visible above the terminal for the red wire). This is more consistent with the diagram in the installation instructions than I had thought.  Between that and the text of step 7 of the installation instructions (which states that the hole for the ground screw is *above* the strain relief bracket rather than *on* the strain relief bracket), I feel fairly confident that I've connected ground to the correct spot. Thank you everyone!